# GWT i18n changing locale

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization

I want GWT to first determine the locale of the user by using 
`<set-configuration-property name="locale.useragent" value="Y"/>`

The URL should be appended with that locale value. Then I'd like to let the user change the language with a listbox and change the URL accordingly.

Is this approach possible and does a change of the URL then result in changing the locale or won't this work because of the locale.useragent property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for the `locale.searchorder` configuration property is `queryparam,cookie,meta,useragent`, so a query-string parameter will override the user-agent's locale (i.e. what you, and most people, would expect).

Comment: That's nice, so my approach would work out. Thanks for your help (: